# What does @Option(longName = "fileName") mean in Java?

Tags: java

I have the following lines in a code :

```
interface Options{
             @Option(longName = "fileName"); 
             String name;
}
```

I don't understand what does the @Option mean in here? Also in general what does "@" character mean in Java?

Comment: Annotations. --> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/

Answer (score 1):

[JewelCLI](http://jewelcli.lexicalscope.com/usage.html) uses those [Annotations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/) to represent proxied interfaces.  There's an example of usage [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/).